# Need carification on the JavaScript code behaviour in strict mode

Tags: javascript

In [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode) MDN document about the Strict Mode of JavaScript, under "**Semantic differences -> `this` in function calls**", it's mentioned that:

> When a function was called with [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), if the value was a primitive value, this one was boxed into an object (or the global object for undefined and null). In strict mode, the value is passed directly without conversion or replacement.

I need clarification for this statement. When I test this, I don't see any difference based on the mode (strict or sloppy) of the code.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood the statement.

This is how I've tested:

```js
(function() {
  function a() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  function b() {
    "use strict";
    a.call(2);
  }

  function c() {
    a.call(3);
  }

  b();
  c();
})();
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It works as expected if you put `"use strict";` at top-level, the beginning of the IIFE, or in `a()`. But not if you put it in `b()` or `c()`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior being described depends on whether the function being called is in strict mode, not the caller.

```js
(function() {
  function strict() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this);
  }

  function sloppy() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  function b() {
    strict.call(2);
  }

  function c() {
    sloppy.call(3);
  }

  b();
  c();
})();
```

Normally you put an entire script into strict mode, so the distinction between caller and callee doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I've misunderstood the statement. Now it makes sense.

Comment: The wording in MDN is somewhat ambiguous.